# set alias Name for Table visually

Tags: sql, alias

I want set a second name for my tables which is not in English letter. and when I want insert `Table Name` to a Table as a record, I use its alias name.

I know in each query we can use `as` to set second name, but I don't want do it by this way. I want set it as a property of a table.

Also please tell me how can I access to this property (alias name) in query?

I found [this article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186295.aspx), but I didn't found the `alias field`.

Comment: That article is taking about aliases _within a single query_ - there's no "alias" property for a table that can be used for any query.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that with a view:

```
CREATE VIEW EasyName
AS
SELECT * FROM LongComplicatedTableName
```

So long as the view only represents one table underneath, you can use all CRUD operations on the view.

According to [MSDN](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874%28v=sql.100%29.aspx), the naming restrictions for table names is as follows:

> 1. The first character must be one of the following:
>
>    - A letter as defined by the Unicode Standard 2.0. The Unicode definition of letters includes Latin characters from a through z and
>        from A through Z, in addition to letter characters from other
>        languages.
>    - The underscore (_), "at" sign (@), or number sign (#). Certain symbols at the beginning of an identifier have special meaning in SQL
>        Server. An identifier beginning with the "at" sign denotes a local
>        variable or parameter. An identifier beginning with a number sign
>        denotes a temporary table or procedure. An identifier beginning with
>        double number signs (##) denotes a global temporary object.
>        
>      Some Transact-SQL functions have names that start with
>        double at signs (@@). To avoid confusion with these functions, it is
>        recommended that you do not use names that start with @@.
> 2. Subsequent characters can be:
>
>    - Letters as defined in the Unicode Standard 2.0.
>    - Decimal numbers from either Basic Latin or other national scripts.
>    - The "at" sign, dollar sign ($), number sign, or underscore.
> 3. The identifier must not be a Transact-SQL reserved word. SQL Server reserves both the uppercase and lowercase versions of reserved words.
> 4. Embedded spaces or special characters are not allowed.
> 5. Supplementary characters are not allowed.
>
> When used in Transact-SQL statements, identifiers that fail to comply
>   with these rules must be delimited by double quotation marks or
>   brackets.

Comment: can i use un-English letter instead of `EasyName`?

Comment: Probably, but it may depend on the collation of the database as to whether or not the name is "unique".  I've added the naming standards from MSDN.